# SQL Server 2012 geography - find minimum of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, geography

I am trying to find the distance to the nearest bike rack to the location of a crime.  I have a database table with 5 million crimes and 5,000 bike racks.  What I need to do now is find the nearest bike rack to each of the 5 million crimes.  I tried creating a python script using geopy but it was simply too time consuming in processing (would have taken weeks at least).  I have been searching online extensively, I have found that SQL Server 2012 has a geography datatype so I created a column containing that geography datatype from the latitude and longitude points of crimes and bike racks.

Now I am trying to do something like this:

```
update Crimes set distanceToNearestBikeRack = crimeGeo.STDistance((select geo from bike_racks))
```

Unfortunately, this would cause the subquery to return many rows and that throws:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

How can I find the nearest point from a multitude of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use `MIN` to find a minimum of a set of values, but it appears it doesn't play well with spatial methods. This works, however:

```
UPDATE
   Crimes
SET
    distanceToNearestBikeRack = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 crimeGeo.STDistance(BR.geo)
        FROM bike_racks BR
        ORDER BY crimeGeo.STDistance(BR.geo) ASC)
```

Of course, with five million crimes and five thousand bike racks, this could take... a while. So you'll probably want to look into batching up the updates.

Comment: This is perfect!!! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!  I added a batch to the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to do this calculation once for each crime location, and the subquery will need information about the crime location in order to find the nearest bike rack.

I have not looked into SQL 2012, but in the old days one would have used the Haversine formular, which is actually pretty fast.
See the answer to
[Geolocation and Haversine formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902450/geolocation-and-haversine-formula), or my answer to [How to calculate distance from a GPX file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569980/how-to-calculate-distance-from-a-gpx-file/570048#570048) from a few years ago for a UDF implementation.